# How do I protect user data at rest?

Tags: encryption, php, databases, mysql

I want to encrypt the username, email, and password fields in the database AND encrypt user files at rest. How can I do this? I am aware of software such as Gazzang and since there is not cost published I can only figure that it will cost thousands of dollars each year.

Is there any alternative solution that I can build myself OR use a software that runs on the server that can encrypt the fields and the user files?

Not sure if it makes a difference but I am using PHP/MYSQL and I have cloud servers.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest method of encryption  on a mysql server is [aes_encrypt()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt) using a randomly generated passphrase.

You should not encrypt user passwords,  passwords must always be hashed.  Passwords should be stored using bcrypt or sha256.

Comment: +1 for "don't encrypt passwords".  Passwords should be salted and hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: The simplest method is not always the best. It appears that [aes_encrypt() uses ECB mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html).

Comment: @mikeazo yeah,  and usernames and email addresses are unique and will usually fit in a single AES-128 block.  Can you think of a reason why an IV is really necessary for this type of data?

Comment: @user5621, a lot of my email addresses will not fit in a single 128 bit block (16 characters). That said, let's assume that all email addresses and usernames are no bigger than 16 characters. Are there any glaring issues? No. Still, I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: @mikeazo yeah that is not good enough for me.  I need a reason why its better.  I don't see the concurrent block issue that cbc solves being a problem with this type of data.

Comment: Just to disagree with everyone -- I don't think salting passwords is a wise idea. It only protects the passwords while they're in the database, and in return it forces you to use the plaintext password *everywhere* else (since that's the only thing you can verify with a salted hash). It makes sense if the database is the weakest link in your system, but if it is, you should strengthen it. For example, there is no good way to use challenge/response authentication when the password is stored as a salted hash. There is no way you can store the password only in a secure hardware device. And so on.

Comment: -1. OP asks about encrypting files too. ECB (and thus MySQL's aes_encrypt()) isn't suitable

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Have a look at the SRP protocol as an example on how to store a password in hashed form and still don't have to send it in plain over the wire for checking.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: The password *is* a hash in SRP. But the password isn't stored in hashed form with SRP. Instead, a public key built from the password is stored on the server while the client computes a private key built from the password. (The "password" is the minumum the client -- or someone trying to impersonate the client -- would need to know to authenticate to the server, regardless of what the scheme chooses to call it.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The point is that (a) the data stored at the server (the "public key") is not sufficient to authenticate against this server, and (b) you don't transfer the password (or "minimum needed to authenticate") to the server, i.e. no "using plain text password everywhere else". Also, the "public key" *is a kind of salted hash*.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: I have nothing against SRP. I have nothing against salted hashes. My point is merely that salting *passwords* is a bad idea. SRP does not salt the password. It converts the password (which happens to be a salted hash already) into a public key. If you are arguing that a public key is a "kind of salted hash", I disagree with you. If you mean SRP's public key specifically is a "kind of salted hash", I'm not quite sure what that would mean.

Comment: @mikeazo Wouldn't explicitly setting CBC eliminate the ECB mode problem? i.e. `SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';`.

Comment: @gillytech, yes, clearly that would solve the ECB problem. CBC has [its own issues though](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/malleability-attacks-against-encryption-without-authentication). An authenticated mode of encryption would be best. I can't find anything that says MySQL supports authenticated modes however.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that and reiterating authentication @mikeazo. I am totally into but still a complete novice at cryptography and securing data so all relevant input helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Encryption for data you have to decrypt: use variables to set the key.**

- Don't log the queries containing user input, they will contain the data you are encrypting. If you have to log it, don't give the database user read privileges to the log
- Don't run your database as a privileged user (e.g. local system/root)
- Store the key seperately from the PHP application and instantiate the variable when the database starts
- Encrypt the key with another key that only root can access, openssl in bash is candidate to do this. The database user shouldn't have direct access to both the key and the key encryption key.

**Salted Hashes for data you only need to verify (Passwords).**

[Salting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459902/going-from-unsalted-to-salted-md5-passwords) is incredibly important. I cannot underscore this enough. Using a relatively inexpensive device (roughly 2k) I can run 100m hashes a second in most algos, a higher end device (~6k - mainly used for industrial purposes) I'm able to achieve upwards of 1.2 billion hashes per second (sha, md5, md4 etc.) If your attacker has an FPGA farm trillions of guesses per second are not far fetched. You can view statistics [here](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-plus/#performance)

Using John and non-optimized code, the Linkedin list (hashes without salt) was guessed @ ~70% using default mangling rules in less than 24 hours...  Salt your Hashes.  When your database is exposed, this will give you the time to inform your users to change their passwords without (necessarily) immediately compromising their access.

**Don't store it if you don't need it.**

I know this isn't directly the question, but seriously, it is just as important. Assuming your database is compromised at some point, if it doesn't have data it can't be exposed.

Last: Use best practice security for databases: validate your data, use stored procedures to proces input, and monitor+audit your database access logs.

Comment: Excuse me, what is the benefit of using stored procedures instead of application-level algos to process input? It makes deploys more problematic.

Comment: MD5 with salt won't protect enough. Slow hash should be used instead of MD5.

Comment: @Renra once your application is subverted, it makes it more difficult for an attacker to do things like read a table, when they don't have permit on select.  Setting exec only on stored procedures means you can be more granular with your permissions.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov I tend to agree, bcrypt is a better solution for this, but is not available in the standard [mysql encryption functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) it would have to be implemented in the application layer.

Comment: It's easy to use library that has slow hash implemented. The fact that it's not implemented in MySQL, isn't excuse. You can just send slow hash's output to DBMS and store it there.